# Filedialog error: type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

My programs work when I did not add the If-Else Function... The If Part works, it executes the messagebox. However, the else part didn't work... No idea why... The error is type mismatch and it probably started on this line : Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen) 
Thanks in advance for your help :)

```
Dim FileToOpen As String
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
              (Title:="Please choose a Excel File to Open", _
               FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xlsx(*.xlsx),")
If FileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No file selected", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    Set sheet = wb2.Worksheets(1)
    sheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).range("A1")
    Sheet1.range("B30").Value = FileToOpen
    Workbooks(2).Close
End If
```

Comment: Is `FileToOpen` declared anywhere? `As` what?

Comment: As string its declared on top which I didn't show

Comment: It's kinda relevant to know what types are involved when you're faced with a type mismatch error.. I suggest you [edit] your question to include all the declarations involved in that snippet: give us a nice [mcve] =)

Comment: Also "it probably started on this line" ....have you tried putting a breakpoint (F9) and debugging the code, stepping through, figuring out *exactly* which instruction is throwing the *type mismatch*?

Comment: I have edited my codes . It is that line as the file do not open when I click open and pop out the error

Comment: I get a type mismatch when trying to compare a `String` to `False`.  I'm not sure how you get to the `Open` statement.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - "have you tried putting a breakpoint (F9) and debugging the code, stepping through, figuring out exactly which instruction is throwing the type mismatch?" - Or, more simply, pressing "Debug" when the error is displayed.  ;)

Comment: @YowE3K oh. well, yeah. duh. *(whistles)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an `Exit Sub` in the first branch, so the `Else` is redundant - you could reduce the indentation level by one.

The problem is that `If FileToOpen = False` compares a `String` with a `Boolean` literal, and VBA (rightfully) doesn't know how this is supposed to evaluate: *that* is what's throwing a *type mismatch* error.

`GetOpenFileName` returns a `Variant` that is a `String` then you select a file, or a `Boolean` when the dialog is cancelled - hence, validate the type instead of the value:

```
Dim path As Variant
path = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please choose a Excel File to Open", 
                                   FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xlsx(*.xlsx),")

'path is Variant/Boolean if cancelled, Variant/String if valid.
If VarType(path) = vbBoolean Then
    MsgBox "No file selected", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
    Exit Sub
End If

Debug.Assert VarType(path) = vbString
With Application.Workbooks.Open(path)
    .Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).range("A1")
    Sheet1.range("B30").Value = path
    .Close
End With
```

Comment: There is also more info about it here @RachelChia https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834966.aspx